# date_default_timezone_set or ini_set(date.timezone) for Php7

Tags: php

Both work, but what is the current recommended way for my version? I wish to simply set UTC and avoid strict errors.

My setup would be

index.php calls config.php, config has date_default_timezone_set / ini_set;

No more classes ever warn about lack of timezone.

Does it matter? Both work.

Comment: It doesn't matter. But if you control the server you should set it in your ini file as that's less overheead

Comment: Would take this as an answer mate :)

Comment: I will add it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter as both perform the same function, and as function calls, have the same overhead.

However, in an ideal situation you would set this in your php.ini file which is parsed once at start up and then stored in memory which would be more performant overall.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set both, because you never know whether someone use `ini_get('date.timezone')` or `date_default_timezone_get()`. These results may differ.